# How to position widgets (e.g. buttons, tabels or entry's) within a tkinter multi-frame application?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, position, frame

I'm currently trying to position some widgets at the top of a frame through sticky = 'n'. That frame is positioned beside a bigger frame. However, the widgets remain centered in their own frame. I would like to keep open the space below the e1-e4 labels and entries in the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

# frame construction
topframe=tk.Frame(master,width = 600, height = 50,bg='red')
topframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=2)

leftframe = tk.Frame(master)
leftframe.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

rightframe = tk.Frame(master)
rightframe.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

bottomframe = tk.Frame(master,width = 600, height = 50, bg='green')
bottomframe.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan=2)

# filling in the frame
tk.Label(leftframe, text="e1:").grid(row=1, sticky='n')
tk.Label(leftframe, text="e2:").grid(row=2, sticky='n')
tk.Label(leftframe, text="e3:").grid(row=3, sticky='n')
tk.Label(leftframe, text="e4:").grid(row=4, sticky='n')

canvas=tk.Canvas(rightframe, width=300, height=300,
                 borderwidth = 1, bg ='light grey',
                 highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="blue")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

e1 = tk.Entry(leftframe)
e2 = tk.Entry(leftframe)
e3 = tk.Entry(leftframe)
e4 = tk.Entry(leftframe)
e1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='n')
e2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='n')
e3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='n')
e4.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='n')

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `sticky='nsew'` to `leftframe.grid(...)`.

Comment: Give `leftframe` a distinct color, and perhaps that will help shed light on the problem. (hint: the widgets in the frame _are_ at the top of the frame.)

Comment: Just adding sticky = 'wens' to the leftframe works perfectly. So many thanks for this suggestion, although I  do not really understand why my own approach didn't work.

Comment: @Sjaak ***"do not ... understand why ... didn't work"***: Read up on [Grid.grid-method - option `sticky=`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method)